# T4300 raid support ICH9R chipset

Tags: raid, dell

I have a few old T4300s which I would like to repurpose as 2008 R2 file servers in smaller locations.

These are configured with the Intel ICH9R raid controller for DATA drives. What if any limitations do I need to keep in mind selecting drives for in this system other than matching size and speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICH9R RAID is "FakeRAID" as there is no battery-backed cache, or dedicated XOR processor. I'd be very skeptical of using it. You'd also need to hook it up to another ICH9R machine in a recovery scenario if the motherboard ever died and couldn't be replaced with the same model.

I'd suggest getting a PERC RAID controller. If you can't, I'd recommend using Windows software RAID, given the alternative.

All that said, if you *must* use the ICH9R controller, just getting drives of matching rotational speed should be enough and even that's not actually *required*.